# tensorflow AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'compat' tf 2.15.0

Tags: tensorflow2.0

I am running a geforce rtx 3050, installed the latest nVIDIA Cudnn and drivers available today, on windows 11.

INPUT------------
C:\Windows\System32>python -m deeplabcut

OUTPUT-----------

File "C:Local\anaconda3\envs\DEEPLABCUT\lib\site-packages\deeplabcut_*init*_.py", line 18, in 
tf.compat.v1.logging.set_verbosity(tf.compat.v1.logging.ERROR)
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'compat'

Trying to run the deeplabcut GUI, on 3 200x200 pixel 3 hour long monochrome videos and I am getting this error when trying to train my model.

Deep lab cut version 2023.11.17

I have tried updating deeplabcut, running in administrator mode, and installing more cudnn packages.